# Confusion about function arguments in R

Tags: r, function, arguments

If I declare a function, I can refer to previous arguments:

```
blah <- function( a=1, b=a ) { print(sprintf("a=%d, b=%d", a, b)) }
```

The output is:

```
> blah(10)
[1] "a=10, b=10"
> blah(10, b=30)
[1] "a=10, b=30"
```

However, the following doesn't work:

```
> blah(a=10, b=a)
Error in sprintf("a=%d, b=%d", a, b) : object 'a' not found
```

Actually, this is more or less what one expects; so why does declaring `blah <- function(a=10, b=a)` work? Why is the scope different here than when I am calling the function?

Also, why does the error appear only when `sprintf` is called? Why doesn't it throw an error immediately when calling the function? I am confused.

**Edit:**

Here to explain my confusion. When I declare a function, the parameters are not evaluated. R has lazy evaluation, and the variables are evaluated when needed. Consider this:

```
> blah <- function( a=1, b=print("foo") ) { print( "So far, so good") ; print( b )  }
>
```

There was no evaluation. I am now calling blah:

```
> blah()
[1] "So far, so good"
[1] "foo"
[1] "foo"
```

The first statement in the function is evaluated, *then* the `print("foo")`. However, at that time, a is around -- we have it in the function scope. So why would `b=a` not be evaluated? We are already in the function when it happens, a has been declared.

**Edit 2:**

Before you jump to the wrong conclusions, note that referring to a previous argument is [perfectly fine](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/10/16/default-arguments-and-lazy-evaluation-in-r/) in function declaration in R due to R's lazy evaluation. What I don't understand is why it works in function declaration, but not when I'm calling. I'm not saying that it should or should not work, just wondering about the underlying mechanics of scoping.

Comment: You have no variable "a" in your environment. That is why you get this error. If you define first `a = 150`, for example, it works. "a" in your function and "a" in your environment are different objects.

Comment: So why does it work when I declare a function?

Comment: Well, it does, try it for yourself.

Comment: I don't know how, that is why I'm asking. It does, though. Also, it is correct syntax. See http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/10/16/default-arguments-and-lazy-evaluation-in-r/

Comment: All right, sorry for the misunderstanding. Still, when I am declaring my function with `blah <- function(a=10, b=a) { }` a isn't in my environment, is it? And if it is, when and how was it created?

Comment: From a clean session of R, define `blah <- function(a=10, b=a) { }`, then do `ls()`.

Comment: When I do it, I see only a single object, "blah".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's difference between where the two expressions are evaluated. When you call a function, the parameters are evaluated in the current scope. When you define a function, the parameters are evaluated within the function scope. This usually the behavior you want.

So when you call the function, it's expected that you are in control of all the values passed to the function. You shouldn't have to know what variables are in use internally inside the function. With lazy evaluation, this construction also works:

```
blah <- function( a=1, b=x ) {
   x < a+10
   print(sprintf("a=%d, b=%d", a, b))
}
blah(1)
```

so trying to call

```
blah(1, b=x+5)
```

makes even less sense because technically you shouldn't even know the `x` variable exists inside the function.

You can see the difference in environments with this example. Here we use `parent.frame()` to get the environment where the function was called from.

```
myenv <- function() parent.frame()
foo <- function( a=myenv() ) {
    print(environment())
    print(a)
}
foo()
# <environment: 0x10c8b1948>
# <environment: 0x10c8b1948>
foo( a=myenv() )
# <environment: 0x10bd85ad8>
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

So when the function runs with the default parameter value, it runs in the same environment as the function itself. When you explicitly pass the parameter, it runs in the environment when it was called from (which, in this case, it the global environment).

This means you cannot use the names of parameters of functions as variables when setting other parameter values when calling a function.

Comment: Thank you, that was the answer to my question.

Answer (score 3):

When you do:

```
> blah(a=10, b=a)
```

You are saying: I have a value `10` *in my global envrionment* and I assign it to argument `a`. I have a **variable** `a` *in my global environment* and I assign its value it to argument `b`.
The variable `a` is totally different to the argument `a` of the function! If variable `a` is not defined and you want to give it to the function, `R` will shout.

You will have exactly the same error by doing:

```
 > blah(a=10, b=nonExistingVariable)
 Error in sprintf("a=%d, b=%d", a, b) : object 'NonExistingVariable' not found
```

Comment: I think the last line of code is more explicit than any explanation, I will shorten mine.

Comment: Fine, so why does `blah <- function(a=1, b=a)` work?

Comment: @ January, you defined a function there and allocate it to variable `blah`, your are NOT using the function.